# How to get know switching of tab bar?

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller

Is there any way to get trigger switching of tab bar? I have to do some data clearing when switching tabs. I have a tableview in every tab bar view and data loaded from an Array. So i need to clear all variable when changing tab. please find me a proper solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need - tabBar:didSelectItem: method

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITabBarDelegate/tabBar:didSelectItem:

Comment: Hi @MuhsinaMuhammed -- as a new user, be sure to TICK the answer. In this way you get points, so you can ask more questions.